# How do I connect a Java class from Raspberry Pi my firebase project?

Tags: java, firebase, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect my Java class to firebase but I can only find documentation for how to do so through Android. I am planning on uploading the Java class to a raspberry pi and I need to connect it to firebase so an Android app will not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two SDKs for Firebase that are relevant, but don't apply here. I'll still list them:

1. The Firebase SDK for Android, which is meant to be used in Android apps.
2. The Firebase Admin SDK for Java, which is meant to be uses in JVM applications that run in a trusted environments, such as a server you control.

Your target deployment systems seems to fit neither of those, so (as said) these likely don't apply.

In that case, the best option is probably to check if there's a REST API for the Firebase product(s) that that you are trying to use, and call those with HTTP calls from your Android app.